# Can't create ROR Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Can't create Ruby on rails project using

```
sudo rails new name_of_your_new_app
```

Getting error as below:

```
  run  bundle install

Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
    Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
    Resolving dependencies...
    Using rake 10.4.2
    Using i18n 0.7.0
    Using json 1.8.2
    Using minitest 5.5.1
    Using thread_safe 0.3.5
    Using tzinfo 1.2.2
    Using activesupport 4.2.0
    Using builder 3.2.2
    Using erubis 2.7.0
    Using mini_portile 0.6.2
    Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
    Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
    Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.6
    Using loofah 2.0.1
    Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
    Using actionview 4.2.0
    Using rack 1.6.0
    Using rack-test 0.6.3
    Using actionpack 4.2.0
    Using globalid 0.3.3
    Using activejob 4.2.0
    Using mime-types 2.4.3
    Using mail 2.6.3
    Using actionmailer 4.2.0
    Using activemodel 4.2.0
    Using arel 6.0.0
    Using activerecord 4.2.0
    Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
    Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
    Using bundler 1.6.2
    Using columnize 0.9.0

    Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/bhavesh/.rbenv/versions/rbx-2.2.10/bin/rbx extconf.rb 
    creating Makefile

    make "DESTDIR=" clean

    make "DESTDIR="
    compiling breakpoint.c
    In file included from breakpoint.c:1:
    ./byebug.h:5:10: fatal error: 'ruby/debug.h' file not found
    "#include <ruby/debug.h>"

    1 error generated.
    make: *** [breakpoint.o] Error 1

    make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/bhavesh/.rbenv/versions/rbx-2.2.10/gems/gems/byebug-4.0.2 for inspection.Results logged to /Users/bhavesh/.rbenv/versions/rbx-2.2.10/gems/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1/byebug-4.0.2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing byebug (4.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue.

Make sure that `gem install byebug -v '4.0.2'` succeeds before bundling.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
    bundler: command not found: spring
    Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

Please let me know solution of this problem.

Comment: as the error suggests - "Don't run Bundler as root". Instead try: `rails new name_of_your_new_app`

Comment: How did you install bundler? With sudo or without sudo? Then: After installing bundler and rails, did you made a `rbenv rehash`? And as shivam told you, don't run any rails commands as root.

Comment: @shivam `Don't run Bundler as root` isn't an error, it's a warning message. Error is due to Rubygem failing install `byebug`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed RVM and RBENV. First I uninstalled both. After that I installed ruby and rails as below command

```
brew install ruby
gem install rails
```

Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use sudo. Only following command.

```
 rails new name_of_your_new_app
```

To run this command, you need to install rails. To install rails run

```
 gem install rails
```

Comment: Why downvote? That is actually the answer... you have to create the rails project in a directory you can write as a normal user, not as root, and run `rails new name_of_your_new_app`

Answer (score 0):

Install byebug on your terminal using `gem install byebug -v '4.0.2'` then run bundle install again. Make sure it first completes successfully. And if you want a new rails app just type `rails new name-of-your-app` . No need to use sudo.